# Finding the object key with the value inside the array?

Tags: javascript, object

I know Some people might find this very easy. But It seems to be very difficult to start. If i have array i could have easily done with filter.

Lets say i have this object

```
    const mapData = {family: ["gender", "ethnics"], house: ["wardNumber","livingType"]}
```

Now if I have `atribute = "gender"` How can i find the key  `family`.

if I have `atribute = "livingType"` Then i need  `House`;

Any Javascript pro here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You could get the keys and find with includes.

Methods:

- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for getting own keys from an object,
- [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for finding an item with a callback,
- [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), this checks if an item exists in an array.

```js
const
    mapData = { family: ["gender", "ethnics"], house: ["wardNumber", "livingType"] },
    attribute = "gender",
    key = Object
        .keys(mapData)
        .find(k => mapData[k].includes(attribute));

console.log(key);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `filter()`

```js
const mapData = {family: ["gender", "ethnics"], house: ["wardNumber","livingType"]}

const findKey = (obj,attr) => Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k].includes(attr))[0]

console.log(findKey(mapData,"gender"))
console.log(findKey(mapData,"livingType"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [`Array.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).

If the value is not found, this will return `undefined`.

```js
const data = {family: ["gender", "ethnics"], house: ["wardNumber","livingType"]}

const getKey = val =>
  (Object.entries(data).find(([k, v]) => v.includes(val)) || []).shift();
 
console.log(getKey('gender'));
console.log(getKey('livingType'));
console.log(getKey('non-existing-value'));
```